# Separate logging for rails application in tomcat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, log4j

We have three apps running in tomcat at different context path. I am using the default context settings in context.xml. We would like one one of the applications that logs to STDOUT to be able to log to its own file.

It is a ruby on rails application that creates the logger as below. It is built as war using jruby file and deployed to tomcat.

```
  if ENV["LOG_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end
```

We would like to redirect the output from the app to go to it's own file. At the moment, all output from the rails application goes to `localhost.date.txt file`. Other apps also log to the same file. For instance, a grails app logs unhandled exceptions to the same file.

**Questions:**

1. What is the easiest way to redirect the log output to `STDOUT` from an app at context path `/rails/search` it's own file without changing the application code?

I have tried with log4j.jar being copied to the appropriate folders if they exist or create the folders and copy of they dont as per the docmentation on [tomcat website](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/logging.html) without much luck.

2. How can I stop the app at context `/grails/hello` to stop logging to the `localhost.date.txt` file.

I have disabled root logging to STDOUT in grails app log4j config, but it still logs unhandled exceptions. In its log file I have restricted the stacktrace to 5 lines, but in `localhost.date.txt` file it still prints the full stacktrace. I can disable all logging to consoleHandler, but I cannot do it unless I solve the first question. So any help is appreciated.

**Things Tried:**

1. Use log4j and slf4j to redirect logs to their own file using swallowOutput on context
2. Create new tomcat9 handler, but could'nt marry it to the logging class for rails app
3. Added properties files at `appName/WEB_INF/classes/logging.properties` and the file is created but no output is logged to the file.